# Passing returned value from one function to another with Python

Tags: python, sqlite, raspberry-pi, rfid

I am trying to pass the inputted value from one function to another function. How it works is the user click the Tkinter button which runs the `chk():` function. Once the button is click the user will have to scan their tag (rfig tag) which will read the user's `tagID` and give the `idTag` variable a value. When the `idTag` is returned the `dataCheck():` function will be called and check if the `idTag` value match one of the values in the *userID* column of my sqlite3 database.

My issue is I keep getting the **Error** : *name 'idTag' is not defined*

The command `reader.read()` acts like a input function because the user actually has to scan (or input) their tag before they can continue. I think the problem is the function is being call as soon as the button is being click which is causing the `idTag` variable to still be empty due to the user not having inputted the value yet. Any thoughs?

```
from tkinter import *
import sqlite3 as sql
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from mfrc522 import SimpleMFRC522
reader = SimpleMFRC522()

global idTag
   
# Tkinter button click Command 
def chk():

    # Function that handels getting User ID 
    def tagScanner(idTag):
        #Get user id value
        tagID = reader.read()
        #If tag is scanned 
        if tagID:
            idTag= (tagID,)
            return idTag
            #call Database function to check returned idTag
            dataCheck(idTag)
    
    # Function handels SQLite3 Database     
    def dataCheck(idTag):
        Database = sql.connect('MedaDataBase.db')
        # cursor
        c= Database.cursor()
        #Check if the idTag maches a value in the userID column of sqlite DB
        query = 'SELECT userID FROM Users "WHERE" userID = "idTag"'

        c.execute(query)
        c.fetchone()
           
        if query == idTag: #if userID is returned
            print('User Verified')
        else:
            print('Denied')
        Database.close()

    #Call scanning function 
    tagScanner(idTag)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several issues here

First, get rid of `global idTag` as I think that's just creating scope issues. You don't need a global variable.

`tagScanner()` does not make use of its only input argument, so get rid of it. You're getting the id from `reader`, so this function does not need another input.

You're comparing the input `idTag` in `dateCheck(idTag)` to your query string instead of whatever's returned by the query, that's probably not your intention.

When the interpreter reaches a `return` in a function, the function exits. The last line of `tagScanner()` will never execute, because it returns right before that. Try calling `dataCheck(idTag)` before you return `idTag`

Your sqlite query is always querying for "idTag", e.g. the string of characters "idTag" rather than the value that you read in and assigned to the variable `idTag`. Use `?` to designate that you want to provide a value during the query, see the docs here:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html

Putting it all together:

```
from tkinter import *
import sqlite3 as sql
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from mfrc522 import SimpleMFRC522
reader = SimpleMFRC522()

# Tkinter button click Command 
def chk():

    # Function that handels getting User ID 
    def tagScanner():
        # Get user id value
        idTag = reader.read()
        # If tag is scanned 
        if idTag:
            # call Database function to check returned idTag
            dataCheck(idTag)
            return idTag
    
    # Function handles SQLite3 Database     
    def dataCheck(idTag):
        Database = sql.connect('MedaDataBase.db')
        # cursor
        c = Database.cursor()
        # Check if the idTag maches a value in the userID column of sqlite DB
        query = 'SELECT userID FROM Users WHERE userID = ?'

        c.execute(query, (idTag,))
        row_returned = c.fetchone()
        if row_returned is not None:
            # Found a matching row
            print('User Verified')
        else:
            print('Denied')
        Database.close()

    # Call scanning function 
    tagScanner()
```

Comment: Thanks for the help definitely learned some new things. However, I am getting an error. The error occurs at `c.execute(query, (idTag,) )` and the error  message is : `sqlite3.InterFaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type`

Comment: @tibaH_lluN it's possible that idTag isn't set properly; print it right before the query, what's its value?

Comment: I though I had it fixed till I did this and discovered the root of the problem. `idTag` is returning a tuple of values.